# Socket.io. Como conectar e enviar o id do usuario

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, adonisjs

Por padrão o socket.io gera um id único. Preciso que esse id seja o mesmo id do usuário no banco de dados.
Tem alguma maneira de setar o id?

caso não tenha, como o meu client front recupera o id gerado pelo socket?

Códigos do front

```
this.socket = Ws(wsUrl, {});
this.connection = this.socket.connect(); //qual o id conectado?
this.chat = this.socket.subscribe('chat');
```

Código api adonisjs

```
constructor({ socket, request }) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.request = request;
    console.log(socket.id) //id do client 
}
```